# Is there a difference for discount per unit and discount per purchase total?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I can't find relevant tags for my question so I wonder if this is a good place to ask.

I wanted to ask this a long time ago but keep forgetting.

Let's suppose when shopping for 3 units of specific good with same price, I am being offered one of the following:

**A)** Get 20% off per unit
**B)** Get 20% for total purchase

Now let's suppose each unit's price is **different** while all else stays the same. Would that change anything?

Can you enlighten please?

Comment: _Mathematica_ != _Mathematics_. But if one buys 2 unit at 10€ each with 20% on each one would pay 2*8€. If one buys 2 units and gets 20% on 20€ one would pay 16€.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about *Mathematica*

Comment: @Öskå Hi, can you take a look on my updated question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $p_i$ is the price of the $i^{th}$ item in your shopping cart and that you purchase $n$ items. If we get $20\%$ of each item individually, then we will pay 
$$(1-0.2)p_1+(1-0.2)p_2+\cdots+(1-0.2)p_n.$$
We can factor out $1-0.2=0.8$ to give
$$0.8(p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_n).$$
If we now examine the second equation, we have summed up all of the items and then applied our discount of $20\%$ showing that both scenarios are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)!